# MySQL: SqlExceptionHelper: Cannot execute (select) statement in a READ ONLY transaction

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the following exception trying to read (select) an entity object from a MySQL database in Spring Data JPA.

> SQL Error: 1792, SQLState: 25006
>
> Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction.

Here is the full log:

> INFO ] 2018-04-11 10:10:47.378 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-1] 
>   OrganizationServiceImpl - Finding organization by id: 11408
>
> Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_12_0_, organizati0_.address_1 as address_2_12_0_, organizati0_.address_2 as address_3_12_0_, organizati0_.circulation as circulat4_12_0_, organizati0_.city as city5_12_0_, organizati0_.country as country6_12_0_, organizati0_.created_by as created20_12_0_, organizati0_.created_on as created_7_12_0_, organizati0_.demographics as demograp8_12_0_, organizati0_.fax as fax9_12_0_, organizati0_.frequency as frequen10_12_0_, organizati0_.medium as medium11_12_0_, organizati0_.modified_by as modifie21_12_0_, organizati0_.modified_on as modifie12_12_0_, organizati0_.name as name13_12_0_, organizati0_.notes as notes14_12_0_, organizati0_.phone as phone15_12_0_, organizati0_.state as state16_12_0_, organizati0_.version as version17_12_0_, organizati0_.website as website18_12_0_, organizati0_.zip as zip19_12_0_ from organization organizati0_ where organizati0_.id=? for update
>
> 2018-04-11 10:10:47.381  WARN 3248 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1792, SQLState: 25006
>   2018-04-11 10:10:47.382 ERROR 3248 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction.
>   2018-04-11 10:10:47.382  INFO 3248 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>   2018-04-11 10:10:47.390 ERROR 3248 --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/organizations/edit] due to exception [could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet]
>
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

...

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.lockAndLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1082) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1069) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

...

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]

You can see that all Hibernate is trying to do is a select. It should not matter that the transaction is read only, and in fact, it should be read only.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="organization")
public class Organization implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long org_id;

@Column(name="NAME")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a name")
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS_1")
private String address1;
```

Here is the relevant parts of the service class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class OrganizationServiceImpl implements OrganizationService {
private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

@Autowired
OrganizationRepository repo;

@Override
public Organization findOne(Long id) {
    log.info("Finding organization by id: " + id);

    return repo.findOne(id);
}
```

And the repository interface:

```
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
/**
 * Returns an Organization object and locks the record.
 *
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Organization findOne(Long id);
```

I have tried changing it to @Transactional(readOnly = false), and it gives me the same error. And really, I want this transaction to be read only for this.

This was working, and I tried reverting the last changes I made but it is still broken.

Comment: Apparently I lied, as I just again tried changing it to (@Transactional(readOnly = false), and I was able to read in organizations again. However, this is not ideal. And I would like to know why Hibernate is trying to write during a select.

Comment: It's not trying to write but it's executing the `SELECT` with the `... FOR UPDATE` clause, which hints the database that the records may be updated later. (see your logged SQL) I guess this interferes with the `read only`-transaction mode.

Comment: @MicSim I bet you're right. Thank you for pointing that out, I totally missed it.